# Observable array not showing all items in array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout observableArray bound to a table below.

```html
<table id="Users">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td><td>Primary Email</td><td>Product Role</td><td>Active</td><td>EditUser?</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: CustomerUsers">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: UserName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: PrimaryEmail().EmailAddress"></td>
            <td><select></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: StaticActiveText"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind ="click: $parent.EditUser">Edit User</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following view model:

```
function CustomerAdminVm() {
    var vm = this
    this.CustomerUsers = ko.observableArray(GetCustomerUsers());
}
```

My problem is that when the view model initially loads `GetCustomerUsers` it correctly gets the values it needs, and inserts them into the observable array. However, the elements are not displayed in the table.

The strange thing is that if I call the following function:

```
this.AddUserToCustomer = function () {
    if (vm.NewUser) {
        vm.CustomerUsers.push(vm.ActiveUser());
    }
    vm.CloseUserModalDialog();
}
```

The user is added to the array, and correctly displayed in the table.  Even more confusing is that the latest value of the array in the push shows the initial values that are not displayers are in the array.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behavior?

The code for `GetCustomerUsers` is:

```
function GetCustomerUsers() {
    var users = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: ControllerBase + 'Actions/GetAllUsersForCustomer',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) { users = $.map(data, function(item) { return new ObservableUser(item); }); }
    });
    return users;
}
```

And `ActiveUser` is also an `ObservableUser`.

Comment: What is the code for GetCustomerUsers?

Comment: I will add the code, but it's just a simple ajax call

Comment: Your [code works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/zzssvqqu/1/). Please edit your question and make sure we can use it to [repro](http://sscce.org) the issue.

Comment: @Jeroen, it's working in your case because your `$.ajax` function is not asynchronous. Add a `setTimeout` inside it and it will break.

Comment: @manji OP's code has `async: false`...

Comment: @Jeroen, didn't see that, my answer is useless ;(

Comment: @manji no worries, I actually was halfway constructing a fiddle before I realized it. Just another reason OPs need to create a repro in their question, if at all reasonably possible.

Comment: @Jeroen the thing about that is the code does work fine until i tried to get data from the server, then that data was not displayed properly.  I actually found a solution that i posted below.

Comment: But how do you expect us to help if we can't reproduce the problem? :-) You should include actual code or a mock for the server-side code in your question. Otherwise we'd have to resort to *guessing* what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I actually found a work around for this.  Instead of populating the data as part of the constructor I add it after the document is ready

```
function CustomerAdminVm() {
var vm = this
this.CustomerUsers = ko.observableArray();
$(document).read(function(){vm.CustomerUsers(GetCustomerUsers());});
}
```

I'm going to throw a theory out as to what is actually happening, feel free to tell me I am wrong, but the solution does work.

What I believe to be happening is the data is being populated in the viewmodel constructor.  But because the call is a synchronous call the constructor is not completing before the data is being populated.  then the apply bindings function is being called, but because the data is prepoulated before the apply bindings function comes back the data already in the object is ignored because it has no observable change.  During  a normal async operation the call the constructor completes, then the apply bindings function is applied, and then the data comes back and the observable is changed causing an event flag to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to create the ko variable in the constructor and then update it with the ajax values when the data arrives.

```
function CustomerAdminVm() {
    var vm = this
    this.CustomerUsers = ko.observableArray();
    GetCustomerUsers(this.CustomerUsers);
}

function GetCustomerUsers(getData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: ControllerBase + 'Actions/GetAllUsersForCustomer',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) { getData($.map(data, function(item) { return new ObservableUser(item); })); }
    });
}
```